# Search CSS in folder using PHP and change css values

Tags: php, html, css

I'm new to php and need some help.

I have a text box that a user can type in an html color code *(ex:#373737)*. Once they hit the submit button I want find all color codes matching #379BB9 and replacing them with the new color code they typed in the text box. I want to change this entry on all the css files in a folder. What i'm looking for is the php code to make this work. I've found bits and pieces of code but I could make it work. I only put the code here that relates to the button. Thanks for any help you can give.

Here's the original color code: #379BB9

```css
p {
    background-color:#373737;
    border:1px solid #373737;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    color:#379BB9;
 width:60px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
} 

.message {
 background-color:#4f4f4f;
 border:1px solid #373737;
 width:98.5%;
    text-align:center;
 margin-bottom:30px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-transform:none;
    color:#379BB9; 
}

.steps {
    text-transform:none;
 color:#379BB9;
}

div.notinstalled {
  color:#f20723;
}

div.installed {
  color:#2cb517;
}

#content a:link, #content a:visited {
    color:#379BB9;
    font-weight:bold;
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<h2>My example.php</h2>
<?php
Need php here........
?>
<label id="steps">Here you can set the theme color.</label>
<br>
<Form name="default1" method="POST" action="example.php">
<label for="defaultcolor">Theme Color: </label><input style="color:#ffffff" type="text" id="defaultcolor" name="defaultcolor" value="Add color code here">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="setcolor" value="Set Theme Color">
</form>
```

Comment: So you haven't tried anything and looking for ready made code???? :D

Comment: Here let me give you a hint how you can exactly do that..! You need to get all css files and read each CSS file line by line to look for your matching code and if you get hits so then write the new color code instead to that CSS file and then you can see for yourself..!

Comment: As i stated above i've been trying to get this working on my own. I have bits and pieces of php code but its a mess. Anything would be helpful. Even links to code snippets where maybe I can sort it out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code:-

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['setcolor'])){
$arr=glob("css\*.css"); //your css file's path
$colorcode=$_POST['defaultcolor'];    
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
$str=file_get_contents($val);
//$str=preg_replace('/#([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3}(([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3})?\b/',$colorcode, $str); //for replace all colour code
$str=str_replace("#379BB9", $colorcode,$str ); // for replace only desired colour code
file_put_contents($val, $str);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Pradyut, Thanks for helping me out. That code is working but its changing all the color codes. What can I do so it will only change color code #379BB9 in all the files? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: just replace the $str=preg_replace('/#([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3}(([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3})?\b/',$colorcode, $str);  with  $str=str_replace("#379BB9", $colorcode,$str );

Comment: I'd also ensure you sanitise the input, so someone couldn't input `#000000; font-size:99pt; color: red`

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I ended using this... $oem='/#'. "379BB9" .'?\b/';
$str=preg_replace($oem, $colorcode, $str);