# Call value from text file and add to php var

Tags: php, html, text, var

On the following code I'm trying to find out how to determine the value of a line in a text file. I keep getting the error below. I tried many combinations to fix but no luck. I'm new to php so I appreciate any help given.

Once I get the error resolved I'm looking for it to take the color code from the text file "defaultcolor" value and change it to the new color that equals the text box value.

I'm trying to get var $currentcolor to report back the value from the text file. That value is #123456

Here's the error

```
Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '#' found
```

Here's the lines in my text file.

```
currentcolor = #123456 
defaultcolor = #379BB9
```

Here's my php

```html
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['setcolor'])){
$arr = glob("css\*.css"); 
$colorcode = $_POST['defaultcolor'];    
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
$str = file_get_contents($val);
$lines_array = file("example.txt");
$search_string = "currentcolor";

foreach($lines_array as $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $search_string) !== false) {
        list(, $new_str) = explode("=", $line);
    }
}
$currentcolor = $new_str;
$str = preg_replace($currentcolor, $colorcode, $str); 
file_put_contents($val, $str);
}
}
echo '<label id="steps">Here you can set the theme color.</label>';
echo '<br>';
echo '<Form name="default1" method="POST" action="example.php">';
echo '<label for="defaultcolor">Theme Color: </label><input style="color:#000000" type="text" id="defaultcolor" name="defaultcolor" value="#379BB9">';
echo '<br>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="setcolor" value="Set Theme Color">';
echo '</form>';
echo '<br>';
?>
```

Comment: First glance... I don't think you need `preg_replace`. I bet `str_replace` is sufficient, and would solve your regex delimiter error.

Comment: I changed it to str_replace with no errors but now when I click on the "Set Theme Color" button it doesn't replace the values in the css files. I'm looking for it to change one value in the css to another.

Comment: Try echoing out the values before the str replace function to debug it. I'm not home so can't test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_replace` (http://php.net/str_replace ) instead of `preg_replace` (http://php.net/preg_replace).

```
$str = str_replace($currentcolor, $colorcode, $str);
```

`preg_replace` will attempt to use regular expression to perform the substitution but it appears you are only doing a simple string substitution.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801904/search-css-in-folder-using-php-and-change-css-values/39802447#39802447

Comment: the str_replace worked with no error but now it wont write the new color code to the css files. Shouldn't it replace $currentcolor with $colorcode? Sorry, I'm new to this. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a

```
die($currentcolor)
```

before you run the `preg_replace`. It needs to wrap with special symbols (such as `#`)

Matt

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace is a regex function thus requires delimiters. It seems PHP thinks you are trying to use '#'as a delimiter. So if you got '#123456", it thinks you want to capture '123456' and tries to warn you that the right-side '#' is missing. So like Clayton says, you'd probably want to consider using a string replace.